# Find an object in ArrayList and remove it

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList called Items.

I want to loop through the ArrayList and search for names, prices. If the name & price matches the input from user and the price is higher than before, I want to remove the old object (containing the name and price, then add the new item(from input) to the ArrayList.

Basically if my ArrayList contained: (Milk, 15)

And input below was Milk, 19

The new ArrayList would now contain: (Milk, 19)

**Edit** from Comments: How do I declare the selected object and remove it?

```
System.out.println("Item name: ");

String name = input.nextLine();

System.out.println("Price: ");

int price = input.nextInt();

Item newItem = (Name, price);



for (Items i: itemList) {

    if(i.getName().contains(name) && i.getPrice()==price)) {


        // here declare object which contains name & price

        //Not sure if below would work but something along these lines

        if(price > object.getPrice()) {

            itemList.remove(object above)

            //and then

            itemList.add(newItem)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, have you tried running your code?

Comment: It sounds like you need a `Map<String, Integer>`, not an `ArrayList`.

Comment: @OldProgrammer yes, but I need help declaring the selected object and then removing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You CAN NOT modify an `ArrayList` while iterating through it. You need to remember which item to remove and remove it after iterating.

```
List<Item> itemToRemove = new LinkedList<Item>(); 

for (Items i: itemList) {

    if(i.getName().contains(name) && i.getPrice() == price)) {

        itemToRemove.add(i);
    }
}

itemList.removeAll(itemToRemove);
```

Comment: Thanks, great solution!

Answer (score 2):

One reasonably neat way to do this is to use the `removeIf` method and then add the new item if anything is removed. `removeIf` returns `true` if anything is removed:

```
if(items.removeIf(item -> item.getName().equals(name) && item.getPrice() > price))
    items.add(new Item(name, price));
```

Note: this code requires Java 8

Comment: Lambdas. Good choice

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you should use a `Map<String, Integer>` instead. A Map/Dictionary/etc is something which stores key/value pairs, it's meant for exactly this type of thing:

```
Map<String, Integer> values = new HashMap<>();

//example logic of utilizing the map to replace values and store the highest
public int addBet(String name, int amount) {
    //in Java 7 or less:
    Integer old = values.get(name); //get the old value
    if (old == null) {
        old = amount; //if there was no old value, we'll use the new one
    } else {
        old = Math.max(old, amount); //if there was a value, use the highest
    }
    return values.put(name, old); //set the amount
    //In Java 8, we have #compute for this instead:
    return values.compute(name, old -> old == null ? amount : Math.max(old, amount));
}
```

So, using this, we could see the highest value via `#addBet`, which demonstrates the map usage:

```
addBet("Bob", 10); //returns 10
addBet("Foo", 14); //14
addBet("Bob", 22); //22
addBet("Bob", 15); //22
values.get("Bob"); //22
values.get("Foo"); //14
```

Additionally, this is much more efficient than iterating an entire list every time.